# psad is failing to send emails through mandrill smtp with postfix

Tags: postfix, mail

I have installed [psad](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-psad-to-detect-network-intrusion-attempts-on-an-ubuntu-vps) on my Ubuntu 13 system and I've set it up to send emails (I have [postfix](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-12-04) installed as mail server with a smtp relay to [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com)'s servers) to some email address, but it seems like what it sends it's not compliant with mandrill's filters.

This would be an API call that reaches mandrill:

```
{
    "from_email": null,
    "from_name": null,
    "send_at": null,
    "async": false,
    "raw_message": "Received: from pulsr.io (unknown [95.85.35.223])\n\t(Authenticated sender: MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY@gmail.com)\n\tby ip-10-75-135-250 (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id C030E3C0CF4\n\tfor <rolandjitsu@gmail.com>; Mon, 14 Apr 2014 15:10:27 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: by pulsr.io (Postfix, from userid 0)\n\tid 7E42B61753; Mon, 14 Apr 2014 11:10:27 -0400 (EDT)\nSubject: [psad-status] firewall setup warning on pulsr!\nTo: <rolandjitsu@gmail.com>\nX-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)\nMessage-Id: <20140414151027.7E42B61753@pulsr.io>\nDate: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 11:10:27 -0400 (EDT)\nFrom: root@pulsr (root)\n\n[-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the /sbin/ip6tables\n    'filter' 'INPUT' chain on pulsr.  For more information,\n    see the file \"FW_HELP\" in the psad sources directory or visit:\n\n    http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html\n",
    "ip_pool": null,
    "to": [
        "rolandjitsu@gmail.com"
    ],
    "return_path_domain": null,
    "key": "MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY"
}
```

And they would respond with:

```
[
    {
        "email": "rolandjitsu@gmail.com",
        "status": "rejected",
        "_id": "a8c60b80ad3745e48398516bea7ca768",
        "reject_reason": "invalid-sender"
    }
]
```

It must be something with the `raw_message` string, since other emails that succeed have the same `null` values on the properties, but with a different `raw_message`.

An example of working email would be:

```
{
    "async": false,
    "send_at": null,
    "ip_pool": null,
    "from_name": null,
    "to": [
        "rolandjitsu@gmail.com"
    ],
    "return_path_domain": null,
    "raw_message": "Received: from pulsr.io (unknown [95.85.35.223])\n\t(Authenticated sender: MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY@gmail.com)\n\tby ip-10-33-35-82 (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 894FE2031D\n\tfor <rolandjitsu@gmail.com>; Mon, 14 Apr 2014 12:52:04 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: by pulsr.io (Postfix, from userid 0)\n\tid 51038608D5; Mon, 14 Apr 2014 08:52:04 -0400 (EDT)\nFrom: Pulsr <root@pulsr.io>\nSubject: RKHunter\nTo: <rolandjitsu@gmail.com>\nX-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)\nMessage-Id: <20140414125204.51038608D5@pulsr.io>\nDate: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 08:52:04 -0400 (EDT)\n\nPlease inspect this machine, because it may be infected.",
    "from_email": null,
    "key": "MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY"
}
```

With the response:

```
[
    {
        "email": "rolandjitsu@gmail.com",
        "status": "sent",
        "_id": "ab8df939be544023a8afb77be5a1e7a8",
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]
```

I've been trying for two days now to figure out what is going on but I have no clue. A little help would be great, if anyone encountered the same issue before (maybe with Google's SMTP as relay).

**EDIT**: My Postfix `/etc/postfix/main.conf` file:

```
# RFC requirement
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)

# Local user mail notification off
biff = yes

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination

# Hostname
myhostname = pulsr.io

# Domain
mydomain = pulsr.io

#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#virtual_alias_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts.txt

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

mydestination = pulsr localhost.pulsr.io localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Mandrill
relayhost = [smtp.mandrillapp.com]
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes

# Add Missing Headers
always_add_missing_headers = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by changing my machine hostname to a valid FQDN hostname inside `/etc/hostname`.

Before:

```
pulsr
```

Now:

```
pulsr.io
```

It seems like postfix was not responsible at all for that, psad or the mta that psad uses is using the hostname of the machine. I would have expected to be handled by postfix at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Mandrill requires that your From email address have a [fully qualified domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). So, root@mydomain.com is accepted, but root@myhost or just root without a domain is not. You might be able to have postfix automatically fix your mail by changing the myhostname or myorigin main.cf values to include your full domain.

Comment: I've tried something like that before with Postfix, I'll try it again

Comment: I have just tried that without luck. I'll post my config file too, perhaps I'm doing it wrong.